# MySQL partitioning relatively large DB Table

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning

I have table structure similar to the following -

```
CREATE TABLE `ProductCatalog` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SerialNumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BasePrice` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BatchCode` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemCode` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ArrivalDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertTimestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `BrandID` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Model` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'RX209',
  `Description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY 'idx_ic_sn_ad' (`ItemCode`, `SerialNumber`, `ArrivalDate`),
  KEY 'idx_sn_ad' (`SerialNumber`, `ArrivalDate`, `ItemCode`, `BasePrice`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

There are about 600 Million rows in this table and is growing fastly. Everyday about 0.5 million records are inserted sometimes more sometimes less. So there is massive write activity going on  during certain period of the day (6 am to 8 pm)

Following are the queries I run against this table

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProductCatalog  
WHERE SerialNumber='1234567890' 
  AND ItemCode!="ABCD" 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
    
SELECT BasePrice 
FROM ProductCatalog 
WHERE SerialNumber='123456789' 
  AND ItemCode!="ABCD" 
  and ItemCode!="PQRS" 
  AND ItemCode!="MNOP" 
ORDER BY ID Desc LIMIT 1
    
SELECT * 
FROM ProductCatalog 
WHERE SerialNumber='123456789' AND ItemCode='ABCD'
  AND (ArrivalDate>='2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND ArrivalDate<='2020-12-31 23:59:59')  
ORDER BY ArrivalDate ASC

SELECT BatchCode
FROM ProductCatalog 
WHERE SerialNumber='123456789' 
  AND ItemCode!="ABCD" 
  and ItemCode!="PQRS" 
  AND ItemCode!="MNOP" 
ORDER BY ID Desc LIMIT 1
```

Above queries and table indexes are optimized as suggested in my previous question here
[MySQL table proper indexes for performance optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/285400/mysql-table-proper-indexes-for-performance-optimization)

**PROBLEM**

Since `ProductCatalog` Table is getting bigger, and third query mentioned above is frequently used, I am thinking of partitioning this table. For this I am thinking of range partitioning using `ArrivalDate` column. Following is the query I came up with.

```
ALTER TABLE ProductCatalog PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(ArrivalDate)) (
PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2011-01-01')),
PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-01-01')),
PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-01-01')),
PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2014-01-01')),
PARTITION p15 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-01-01')),
PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2016-01-01')),
PARTITION p17 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2017-01-01')),
PARTITION p18 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-01-01')),
PARTITION p19 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-01-01')),
PARTITION p20 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2020-01-01')),
PARTITION p21 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2021-01-01')),
PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE);
```

Later every year I will re-organize the partition like this

```
ALTER TABLE ProductCatalog 
REORGANIZE PARTITION p22 INTO (
    PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2022-01-01')),
    PARTITION p23 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2023-01-01')),
    PARTITION p24 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

**QUESTIONS**

Every year about 200 Million rows in average are inserted. So taking this into consideration -

1. Do this partitioning do any good in terms of performance with my existing table structures and indexes.
2. Do this partitioning do any good for selects statements I have specified above?
3. Do this partitioning do any good for lots of inserts going every moment?
4. I know we can delete particular partition, but is it easily possible to archive particular partition  to another archive database before deleting?
5. Is there any other better idea, to get maximum possible read and write performance in the database?
6. Do I need to worry about column `id int(10)` when data is increasing rapidly?
7. What this partitioning will impact on other three queries where no `ArrivalDate` is used in `WHERE` condition?

Comment: *I am thinking of range partitioning using ArrivalDate column.* This makes no sense. Only one query filters/sorts the rows by this column, all another queries will scan all partitions. All queries uses filtering by `SerialNumber` - so partitioning by this column will be the most effective.

Comment: @Akina. Yes but the third query with column `ArrivalDate `, is used very frequently and the customer has been complaining performance issue on the page where this third query is used.

Comment: Use subpartitioning by date.

Comment: If you do decide to partition by date, always have one more partition than you need at the top (e.g. include a partition for next year, that will remain empty), so that when the time comes to add the next partition, you are splitting the empty partition rather than a full one.

Answer (score 1):

So going down your list of questions:

> Do this partitioning do any good in terms of performance with my
> existing table structures and indexes.

**No!**  If you *always* query on date, *maybe*.

> Do this partitioning do any good for selects statements I have
> specified above?

Only your third query, and that's a *maybe*.

> What this partitioning will impact on other three queries where no
> ArrivalDate is used in WHERE condition?

It depends on if the secondary indexes are also partitioned.  But generally there can be more overhead as you have to query each partition that possibly contains rows.  Partitioning also breaks a lot of features in MySQL so it shouldn't be undertaken lightly.

> Do this partitioning do any good for lots of inserts going every
> moment?

No.  You're still appending according to the meaningless row identifier.  Everything will be stuck on the last page.

> I know we can delete particular partition, but is it easily possible
> to archive particular partition to another archive database before
> deleting?

I'm not sure about MySQL - moving/deleting partitions is relatively simple in other databases.

> Do I need to worry about column id int(10) when data is increasing
> rapidly?

Yes!  You either fix the problem now or have to rebuild the table with a larger, equally meaningless row identifier and further your woes.

> Is there any other better idea, to get maximum possible read and write
> performance in the database?

Yes.  It's called define the primary key, and cluster on that.

Right now you have a big unorganized mess of rows.  I'd call it a heap, but people reserve that for a certain type of unorganized mess of rows that hides the row pointer from the user instead of declaring it a primary key.

Your rows are located in the table according to their approximate insert order.  To locate these rows more efficiently you slap an index on top so you can find where they're hidden, but even with the index you could be reading one page per row, or the entire table, depending on how the data is distributed.  See my answer here for a very basic illustration: [Save performance with large update on Index with Included Column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284029/save-performance-with-large-update-on-index-with-included-column/284031#284031)

So it's not entirely obvious from your question if `(SerialNumber, ArrivalDate, ItemCode)` is unique, but let's assume it is (we can adjust later if an additional column is necessary to define uniqueness).  If we define your table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `ProductCatalog` (
  `SerialNumber`    varchar(20)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemCode`        varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `ArrivalDate`     datetime NOT NULL,
  `BasePrice`       decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BatchCode`       tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type`            varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertTimestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `BrandID`         tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Model`           varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'RX209',
  `Description`     text,
  CONSTRAINT PK_ProductCatalog PRIMARY KEY (SerialNumber, ItemCode, ArrivalDate)
)
```

Three things happen:

1. We save space because we're not slapping an unnecessary row pointer on every row
2. We are guaranteeing uniqueness
3. Rows are now grouped (for the most part) according to `(SerialNumber, ItemCode, ArrivalDate)`.

The consequences of #3 is that all of the queries you submitted will traverse one b-tree and at usually no more than 1-2 pages to satisfy the query.

Yes, this can cause page splits (fragmentation), but the impact of page splits is generally less than the cost of additional indexes (which also fragment) and more read I/O.  If it gets really bad (which you'll monitor just like anything else), you can rebuild the table (clustered index).

Other general observations:

1. Don't store timestamps as anything other than `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP`.  The data type exists for a reason, if you have to convert on insert, that's better than having to convert on read.
2. If one or more of `Brand`, `Model`, or `Description` is dependent on the `ItemCode`, then that data should be stored in its own table.  Makes your main table even more compact.
3. If `SerialNumber` and `ItemCode` are fixed length, you're probably better off using `CHAR(<the max length>)` versus `VARCHAR`.

Comment: *We save space because we're not slapping an unnecessary row pointer on every row* No. We save space because the index not needed at all. PRIMARY is always clustered in InnoDB.

Comment: @Akina - I'm not seeing a disagreement between your statement and mine?  The system generated value costs storage in two ways: 1. space to store it 2. requires additional secondary indexes to facilitate searches.  Yes the primary key is always clustered, hence choosing a better primary key is the preferred method of improving performance in this instance.

Comment: (1) Primary key not exists as disk structure. It is an order of the rows in table's data body file. (2) System generated inner row number exists in **any index**. Including primary (i.e. including the table itself).

Comment: @Akina 1. That applies only to databases that maintain a clustered index (in this case MySQL), but primary key is a *logical* concept that pertains to which key is migrated to child entities.  Physical implementation varies. 2. That is not true with clustered indexes which use the leaf level to store the data (and secondary indexes contain the primary key column(s)).

Comment: 1. DBMS is specified - MySQL. Engine is specified - InnoDB. 2. I cannot understand the relation... or I cannot understand what pointer you have told about in "We save space because we're not slapping an unnecessary row pointer on every row". When clustered index (primary or unique not null) exists then this index expression value is a pointer to the row. Disk space need decreases from initial to your strucure by removing 2 secondary indices and one autoincrement column only. Pointer (PK expression) size increase not affected because of no secondary indices in your structure.

Comment: @Akina The auto-increment in this case serves only as a row pointer.  Just because it is specified as a column and marked "primary key" does not make its function any different - it points to a row.  Eliminating it saves space on *the table* (which would be my primary goal) - yes, savings to the overall database size and insert/update/delete performance are bonuses from no longer needing the secondary indexes.

Comment: Thanks, for detailed reply. `ProductCatalog`, no columns or combination of any columns are unique. The only unique is `ID` column

Comment: @WatsMyName What result does this query return: `SELECT MAX(Rowcount) FROM (SELECT SerialNumber, ItemCode, ArrivalDate, COUNT(*) AS Rowcount FROM ProductCatalog GROUP BY SerialNumber, ItemCode, ArrivalDate) x`

Comment: For all practical purposes, MySQL's `PRIMARY KEY` takes no extra space on disk.  (In reality, it is about 1% of the overall table size.)  Secondary keys, on the other hand, are each a separate B+Tree, so take more space.

Answer (score 0):

You say that that no combination of columns is "unique"?

bbaird rightly suggests `PRIMARY KEY (SerialNumber, ItemCode, ArrivalDate)` to help with performance, but it won't work because of lack of uniqueness?

In that case, do this:

```
 PRIMARY KEY (SerialNumber, ItemCode, ArrivalDate, ID)
 INDEX(ID)
```

This gives you

- The clustering benefit all your queries since you are always filtering on `SerialNumber`
- Having `ID` anywhere in the PK assures that it is unique.
- Keeps AUTO_INCREMENT happy since `ID` is at the *start* of *some* index.
- Takes almost exactly the same disk space as

  ```
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    INDEX(SerialNumber, ItemCode, ArrivalDate)
  ```
- A slight downside is that any further secondary keys will have a copy of the PK in them, thereby being bigger when the PK is bigger.
- PK(ID) orders the data chronologically, which has some benefit for some queries.  All new rows go at the "end" of the data.  PK(something else) arranges the data differently, thereby causing inserts to go in at multiple places.  However, the benefit for SELECTs is likely to oughtweigh the downside.

`PARTITIONing` is not indicated for those queries.  If you will be purging "old" data based on `ArrivalDate`, then your partitioning (and bbaird's comments) do apply.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

`SUBPARTITIONing` is useless (in my experience).

Comment: I'm highly skeptical there's no *logical* combination of rows to guarantee uniqueness, but I'm almost 100% certain there are duplicate rows as there was no proper key defined on the table.  Your solution will work to overcome that limitation, but someone should really figure out exactly what they're storing and build the table appropriately.

Comment: Whenever I see a datetime or timestamp in the PK, I am quite skeptical that it will always be 'unique'.

Comment: Generally, I can't imagine where it is *valid* to have more than one value at a point in time.  "Your price for Item A as of today is... $2.50 or $3.00.  Who knows?" isn't acceptable in my line of work and probably many others as well.

Comment: So if it isn't unique, it's because no one bothered to outline the requirements correctly and use the database to enforce them.

Comment: Two stock trades could happen in the same second.  On the other hand, a "summary tale" might deliverately have no more than one row per day.

Comment: For the same customer/stock symbol?  Unlikely, but that's what queues are for (trades are always settled after the fact).  The actual *balance* of shares in an account, once settled, could not have more than one value in time - madness would ensue.  Like, I feel in each of your "gotchas" the answer is the composite key saves you.